# Error with Facebook PHP SDK Example

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying out the Facebook PHP SDK example at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php on a localhost XAMPP server.

**Problem:** When I click on the `Login with Facebook` button, I get an error on Facebook `An error occurred. Please try again later.`.

Other than this, the rest of the example appear ok, showing the profile pic and profile name.

Any idea what is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up your URLs in the App? Such like Site URL and Site Domain? Otherwise we need more information on how you have set up your code.

Comment: Hi, I setup the Site Domain as `mydomain.com` but was accessing through `localhost`. After uploading to `mydomain.com` and accessing from there, it works!! Now.. how do I add `localhost` as the site domain? Adding `localhost` give me the error `localhost must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.`

Comment: Right, if you want to add localhost (to your machine) you must forward your ports and then in the url and site domain you have to enter your dynamic IP and port number the connection will enter through.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Facebook app and replace the example's appId and secret with your app's?

Comment: Yes I replaced with my appid and secret